# why comming from <a> route "ruta/{{$var}}/edit" and a 'action': "ruta/{{$var}} my final route is: ""ruta/{{$var}}/"ruta/{{$var}}"?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, frameworks, laravel-routing

I have a view whit the next code:

```
<h1>Edicion</h1>
@foreach ($usuarios as $usu)
  <h4>{{$usu->nombre}}</h4>
  <a href="prurequests/{{$usu->slug}}/edit">editar</a>
@endforeach
```

This route:

```
Route::resource('/prurequests','PruebasControllers\PrurequestsController');
```

The method edit:

```
public function edit($slug)
{
  $usuario = Usuario2::where('slug','=',$slug)->firstOrFail();
  return view('vistaspruebas.edit', compact('usuario'));
}
```

In this route my URL is:
[/public/prurequests/vaca/edit](http:///public/prurequests/vaca/edit)

The code in this view 'vistaspruebas.edit' is:

```
<form action="prurequests/suma" method="POST">
  @method('PUT')
  @csrf
  <label for="nombre">ingrese nombre</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" value="{{$usuario->slug}}">
  <br />
  <button type="submit" name="" value="submit">Actualiza</button>
</form>
```

instead of looking for this route: **"prurequests/suma "** Laravel look for **/public/prurequests/vaca/prurequests/suma**

someone knows why after the tag  and call other route it removes 'edit' and change it by and other route i put here?

Comment: <form action="prurequests/suma method="POST"> shoule be <form action="prurequests/suma`"` method="POST">

Answer (score 0):

Please use action() helper method in your form as the following:

```
<form action="{{ action('Controller@method') }}" method="POST">
```

Or you can use the route helper method as the following:

```
<form action="{{ route('route_name') }}" method="POST">
```

Also you can use url() helper if you want to use a given path:

```
 <form action="{{ url('path_here') }}" method="POST">
```

Comment: How can i use it with a variable?  
`<form action="{{ route('prurequests/$usuario->slug') }}" method="POST">`

Comment: @DiegoIzquierdoDussan Please revise the updated answer.